# What is considered a cross-origin request

Tags: cors

So I've been trying to connect my javascript webapp to github's API via a server proxy (to hide the `client_secret`) but I noticed that while I can make HTTP requests (GET,POST etc), I'm not able to do them through my webapp. The server resides in the following url: `http://mydomain.com:3000` while my webapp is at `http://mydomain.com`. When I'm trying to use JQuery's `$.ajax` to do a `POST`, I'm getting the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So my question is whether a request to a different port but in the same domain name is considered a cross-origin request

Comment: A cross-origin request is any difference between host, protocol, or port.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, a request to the same host but on a different port is considered a cross-origin request.

The "origin" in the term "cross-origin" is defined as the scheme, host, and port of a url. For example, in the url https://mydomain.com:3000/foo/bar, the scheme is "https", the host is "mydomain.com" and the port is "3000".

In order for a request to be a same-origin request, the origin (aka the scheme, host and port) must match. All other requests are considered cross-origin. Wikipedia has a great table showing examples of same- and cross-origin requests: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Answer (score 0):

A cross-origin request is any request to a page that is not on your own server, on that same port.

Comment: What if it's in the same server and port but different domain name? What about sub-domains?

Comment: A subdomain should be fine, as far as I know. Same server and port should also be fine, since they're just different names for the same thing

Comment: not on your own server isn't specific in technical terms. The question is specific "whether a request to a different port but in the same domain name is considered a cross-origin request"